# Перенести .htaccess на Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, apache2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Решил перейти на nginx, но не могу сообразить как правильно переписать правила htaccess. Ниже правила htaccess:

```
 AddDefaultCharset utf-8

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
 <Files .*>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny From All
 </Files>

# Redirect to www
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !robots\.txt$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
  RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [R=301,L]


# Redirect urls with no trailing slash
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/odminka/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/guide
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.txt$

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
  RewriteRule .+ $0/ [R=301,L]


# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
  RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Comment: https://winginx.com/ru/htaccess

Comment: к сожалению, я это уже пробовал, как и пробовал гуглить, на текущий момент работает только главная страница, редирект на www я переписал, но вот остальное увы нивкакую

Answer (score 0):

```
#redirect to www
server {
listen 80;
server_name test.ru;
return 301 $scheme://www.test.ru$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  root /gopanel/sites/www_test_tu/www;
  index index.php;
  server_name www.test.ru;


# Prevent access to hidden files
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ { 
try_files $uri =404; 
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; 
fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY ""; 
fastcgi_index index.php; 
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
include fastcgi_params; 

fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.+)$;
} 

#Deny access to Git catalog
location ~ /.git/ {
    deny all;
}

#Защититься от запросов к несуществующим файлам
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
 #my 404
  location = /404.html {
    root /gopanel/sites/www_test_tu/www;
    internal;
}


}
```